# Does the Hubble constant measured for huge distances mean it is not the actual Hubble constant but a very old one?

Tags: time, astronomy, universe, dark-energy

I am citing Wikipedia about Hubble constant....

"Hubble constant is most frequently quoted in (km/s)/Mpc, thus giving the speed in km/s of a galaxy 1 megaparsec (3.09×1019 km) away, and its value is about 70 (km/s)/Mpc. However, the SI unit of H0 is simply s−1 and the SI unit for the reciprocal of H0 is simply the second. The reciprocal of H0 is known as the Hubble time. The Hubble constant can also be interpreted as the relative rate of expansion. In this form H0 = 7%/Gyr, meaning that at the current rate of expansion it takes a billion years for an unbound structure to grow by 7%."

Now my question could be a mistake but I will ask it nevertheless its possible unclearness.
The universe grows 7% in a billion years and the Hubble constant measured for closer distances and farther distances is the same.Is this telling us **that it was of same value for a huge amount of time** just for the reason that farther distances give us the picture of a past time which should give us a very old H  but which is measured equal to the one measured for closer distances which should be the acctual one?If it is true then the next question will be very hard to accept.... "When the universe was for example just 1 million light years big does it mean that to increase by 7% to just 1.1 million light years it would have taken 1 billion years for doing so?"

Answer (score 1):

We can't measure the distance or velocity of distant objects directly. We'd have to calculate them from redshift and apparent magnitude, and the result depends strongly on the model used to do the calculation.

Estimates of $H_0$ either come from more-or-less direct measurements of nearby objects or from fitting a cosmological model to a wide variety of data and then computing the constant from the model. In both cases the result is the Hubble parameter of the current cosmological era, not any previous era—in the former case because that's the data they have, and in the latter case because that's the value they choose to compute and report.